# jQuery Plugin for automatically updating scrolling list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I am trying to make a regular list (not drop-down), that can be automatically updated using a textfile on a webpage. 
I am open to any suggestions on plugins or direction to write the code

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  It might be worth revisiting the [tour] and also have a read of [ask].  Some topics are considered off-topic, specifically asking for a plugin.  We're here to help with specific problems that you've encountered.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am sorry if my question was out of the rules. I will look into it and take note of them next time. thanks!

Comment: @habib I have tried to manually convert the drop down list to regular list, however, I lose the functionality of being able to select